# HTML/CSS: Floating element in H2 element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

This is the HTML:

```
<h2>
  Log in
  <a onclick="doSomething()" href="#" class="float-right">&nbsp;</a>
</h2>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.float-right {
    float: right;
    background: url(img.png);
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

So this should make the `.float-right` element float to the right of the text in the header, but in IE7 it doesn't! I don't care about IE6, I just have to get this working in IE7 and newer.

Comment: What is the CSS of h2?  What is the width?  Put a border on the h2 element and see what the width is.

Comment: The CSS for `h2` is just `font-size`, `font-weight` and `padding-bottom`... Should be irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to move the code around?

```
<h2>
  <a onclick="doSomething()" href="#" class="float-right">&nbsp;</a>
  Log in
</h2>
```

Comment: I think it's because h2 by default is a block, which takes up 100% width. IE calculates it's width before seeing the floated element. but this is just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

try adding `display:block;` to the css

Comment: Yes, thats what is missing, also see my other comment.

Comment: I thought `display: block` is implied on floated elements...and it still doesn't work when I add that rule.